# Upload big image to server by dividing image in small chunks

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, chunks

I want to upload my big images on sever.
Is it possible to convert them in chunks and upload it on sever?

Here is my code for uploading image how can i send image in Chunks??

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSString *result = [df stringFromDate:assetDate];

    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [assetDate timeIntervalSince1970];
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [temp defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    StrPath = [StrPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d.%@",(int)timeInterval,strImageType];
    //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];

    UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:[rep scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[rep orientation]];
    //------------------ metadata -------------------------------------------------------
    NSDictionary *imageMetadata = [rep metadata];
    NSString *strOrt=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageMetadata valueForKey:@"Orientation"]];

    NSData *dataObj = nil;
    dataObj = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    NSString* StrFileData = [Base64 encode:dataObj];
    NSString* strFileHash = [dataObj md5Test];

    NSMutableDictionary *DictRequest = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [DictRequest setObject:srtprefSessionId forKey:@"SessionId"];
    [DictRequest setObject:StrPath forKey:@"Path"];
    [DictRequest setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isTrash] forKey:@"UploadDirectlyToTrashbin"];
    [DictRequest setObject:StrFileData forKey:@"FileData"];
    [DictRequest setObject:strFileHash forKey:@"FileHash"];
    [DictRequest setObject:result forKey:@"DateCreated"];

    BOOL isNULL = [self stringIsEmpty:strOrt];
    if(!isNULL)
    {
        //[DictRequest setObject:strOrt forKey:@"Orientation"];
    }


    NSString *jsonString = [DictRequest JSONRepresentation];
    NSString *strUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",FileUpload_URL];
    NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSData *postData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    if(theConnection)
        [self Set2Defaults];

    theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    if(theConnection)
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    else
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed !!!");
```

Comment: Yes you can split the image in to small chunk and upload to server and you can concatenate the image over the server

Comment: What problem you are facing??

Answer (score 0):

There may be chance of data packet lost while you are sending data to server. Cause of packet loss may be jitter, low bandwidth ,overcrowded Channel.
Try to small Image size size and send it as whole so that u can retrieve it with its original encoded data byte in stream channel

Answer (score 0):

Convert your image to utf8 string send that string in chunks and concatenate and convert to image at server end.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your image to data using conversion, and send this on server asynchronously.